# Markdown in JS without enclosing <p>?

Tags: javascript, markdown

How can I convert a piece of markdown text to HTML using any JS library like markdown-js or marked without enclosing it in paragraph tag?

For example I like to convert `this *italic* text` to `this <i>italic</i> text` without enclosing it in `<p></p>`.

Edit:
- My question is not how to remove p tags from output after conversion, my question is how to ask the library not to enclose output in p tags.
- markdown-js and marked enclose output inside `<p></p>` by default.

Comment: What is the issue with this? Can you not parse it after it's been converted in order to get the output you want. It seems an odd request and I'm doubtful you'll find that out of the box.

Comment: @LouBichard Your comment actually is a markdown text converted to HTML without being enclosed in `<p></p>`, so it is not an odd request!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) has [md.renderInline()](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it#usage) method which allows to do that.

Answer (score 13):

The [**marked**](https://github.com/chjj/marked) library allows you to define your own renderer, which allows you to define the output for paragraphs.

You can pass in your own renderer by using:

```
marked.setOptions({
  renderer: new MyRenderer(),
});

var output = marked('This **text** will be rendered with MyRenderer');
```

This will require you to define methods for `blockquote`, `html`, `paragraph` and all the other methods that the default `marked.Renderer` defines.

Here is an example:

```
function MyRenderer(options) {
  this.options = options || {};
}

MyRenderer.prototype.paragraph = function(text) {
  return 'This comes from my own renderer: ' + text + '\n';
};
```

However, this requires some efforts, so the **quickest** way to get rid of the paragraphs (`<p>` tags) is to change the code of the existing Renderer in the `marked.js` file:

Replace:

```
Renderer.prototype.paragraph = function(text) {
  return '<p>' + text + '</p>\n';
};
```

With:

```
Renderer.prototype.paragraph = function(text) {
  return text + '\n';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, if the default 'Renderer' is exposed it would be easy to extend or change it.

Comment: You could create an instance of the default Renderer with `new marked.Renderer()` and then override it's `paragraph` function and then pass this instance into `marked.setOptions`.

Comment: That solution has one problem: all paragraphs will be without p-tags.

Comment: This works for us using `angular-marked` `1.0.1` but not with `angular-marked` `1.2.2`. I've not investigated any further, but this may help others.

Comment: marked now has this option: `marked.parseInline('**strong** _em_');` which strips the <p>

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by using a regex on the result:

```
rawMarkup.replace(/^(?:<p>)?(.*?)(?:<\/p>)?$/, "$1")
```

This will however **only work on simple cases**, and will fail in cases where there are two adjacent paragraphs, and possibly others.

After some testing I realized that there is a good reason why there are paragraph tags around the text, and that my implementation will have to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late to the game on this question, but I had the exact same problem last night, and I opened up **marked** in order to build a solution to this issue.

I need to be able (for my i18n translation CMS) to embed tags inside any kind of tag, like headers, and have them render from Markdown without the enclosing `<p>` tag. So this fix makes it so that if there is only one line of text in my source (which for me is JSON), then it will not wrap in `<p>` tags. But if there is more, it will wrap them all in tags as normal.

> Here is my pull request for the change
>   https://github.com/chjj/marked/pull/841

I highly doubt it will be included, but I am using it in my project and it works wonderfully.

Comment: marked now has this option: `marked.parseInline('**strong** _em_');` which strips the <p>

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me (many years later). It assumes that you know what elements you don't want to wrap in paragraph tags.

```js
const marked = require("marked");

// Every new line in markdown is considered a new paragraph, this prevents
// img tags from being wrapped in <p> tags which is helpful for resizing img's, 
// centering captions, etc.
marked.Renderer.prototype.paragraph = (text) => {
  if (text.startsWith("<img")) {
    return text + "\n";
  }
  return "<p>" + text + "</p>";
};

html = marked(markdownFile.body)
```

Comment: marked now has this option: `marked.parseInline('**strong** _em_');` which strips the <p>